# how to randomly create a picture in a box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to randomly generate a picture from a selection I have within a box. So far I have this code set to go on a mouse click:

```
    function randomize(){
        var imgDestination = document.getElementById("stage");
        var imgAdded = imageRandomizer();
        imgDestination.appendChild(imgAdded);
        ImgRandomPosition(imgAdded);
    }

    function ImgRandomPosition(imgAdded){
        var left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 1)+"px";
        var top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1)+"px";
        var imagestyle = imgAdded.style;
        imagestyle.position = "absolute";
        imagestyle.top = top;
        imagestyle.left = left;
    }

    function imageRandomizer(imgArray, path) {
        path = 'img/';
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
        var img = imgArray[num];
        var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
        document.write(imgStr);
        document.close();
    }
```

I don't know how to get the appendchild working. do you know how I can maybe fix that,
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem you have?

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to include that, my apologies. I believe the appendchild might not be allowed since I have var imgAdded=imageranodmizer. do you know how I can maybe fix that

Answer (score 0):

Since `imageRandomizer` doesn't return anything, the line `var imgAdded = imageRandomizer()` in your `randomize` function does not make any sense, because `imgAdded` will be always `undefined`.

A solution to this would be creating an image element and setting its `src` and `alt` properties in your `imageRandomizer` function, instead of creating the HTML of the image and trying to parse it using `Document.write`.

**Code:**

```
function imageRandomizer(imgArray, path) {
  var
    /* Generate a random index from the array. */
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length),

    /* Cache the src string saved at the random index. */
    src = imgArray[random],

    /* Create a new image element. */
    image = new Image();

  /* Set a default value to path, if a falsey value is given. */
  path = path || 'img/';

  /* Set the 'src' and 'alt' properties of the image. */
  image.src = path + src;
  image.alt = "";

  /* Return the created image. */
  return image;
}
```

Comment: I tried this out but I keep getting told that src is an unused variable. do you have any idea why that might be? Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: I made some edits to the code. Give it another try @tA.